# Is it possible to convert(OCR) jpeg images to text using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, jpeg, ocr, google-docs

I know that it is possible to manually convert(OCR) jpeg images stored on Google Drive to text (when we open the jpeg images using Google Docs). What I wish to know is whether the same is possible via scripting.

The reason for this is that it would help me convert a bulk of images with text (around 400) into text files at one go.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that your problem is now resolved one way or the other, but for the reference of others who may find this question, I believe that the [Google DocumentsList API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_documents_using_optical_character_recognition_ocr) will do what you need.

Comment: Not as easy as I was hoping, but I think this solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This other answer is not correct. Blob.getdataasstring will NOT work. It will produce garbage text (it simply converts the binary blob to string data NOT ocr. Its not possible to do this with apps script. In drive its not possible either even thou you say its possible in your summary. Drive will Index the ocr text but you cant get to that text.

Comment: Actually I have used Google Drive to OCR jpeg files. All you have to do is select a jpeg file and Open As Document. The jpeg is converted into OCR text.

Comment: with the drive interface. in fact it is also possible to upload jpeg files and have them directly converted to gdoc format (along with OCR).

what i wish to find out if the same can be achieved through the code.

Comment: ok, my answer is wrong then. Wasnt like this a couple years ago.